# Simulate clicking a link inside a link - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Python Knowledge: beginner

I managed to create a script to scrape contact information. The flow I followed since I am a beginner is to extract all the first links and copied it to text file and this is being used in *link = browser.find_element_by_link_text(str(link_text))* Scraping of contact details have been confirmed working (based on my separate run). The problem is that after clicking the first links, it won't go on clicking the links inside it, hence it cannot scrape the contact info.

What is wrong with my script? Please bear in mind I am a beginner so my script is a little bit manual and lengthy.
Thanks very much!!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import csv, time, lxml

######################### open file list ####################################
testfile = open("category.txt") # this is where I saved the category
readfile = testfile.read()
readfilesplit = readfile.split("\n")
############################### end ###################################

################### open browser ###############################
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://aucklandtradesmen.co.nz/')
####################### end ###################################

link_texts = readfilesplit
for link_text in link_texts:

        link = browser.find_element_by_link_text(str(link_text))
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".add-listing")))

        link.click() #click link
        time.sleep(5)

        print "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        print("Getting listings for '%s'" % link_text)

################# get list name #######################
        urlNoList = 'http://aucklandtradesmen.co.nz/home-mainmenu-1.html'
        r = requests.get(browser.current_url)

        if (urlNoList != browser.current_url):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

            g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"listing-summary"})
            pageRange = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"xlistings"})

            pageR = [pageRange[0].text]
            pageMax = str(pageR)[-4:-2] # get max item for lists

            X = str(pageMax).replace('nd', '0')
            # print "Number of listings: ", X
            Y  = int(X) #convert string to int
            print "Number of listings: ", Y

            for item in g_data:
                try:
                    listingNames = item.contents[1].text
                    lstList = []
                    lstList[len(lstList):] = [listingNames]

                    replStr = re.sub(r"u'",  "'",str(lstList)) #strip u' char

                    replStr1 = re.sub(r"\s+'",  "'",str(replStr)) #strip space and '

                    replStr2 = re.sub(r"\sFeatured",  "",str(replStr1)) #strip Featured string
                    print "Cleaned string: ", replStr2

                    ################ SCRAPE INFO ################
################### This is where the code is not executing #######################
                    count = 0
                    while (count < Y):
                        for info in replStr2:
                            link2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text(str(info))
                            time.sleep(10)
                            link2.click()
                            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#rating-msg")))
                            print "count", count
                            count+= 1
                            print("Contact info for: '%s'" % link_text)

                            r2 = requests.get(browser.current_url)

                            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'html.parser')

                            g_data2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"fields"})

                            for item2 in g_data2:
                            # print item.contents[0]
                                print item2.contents[0].text
                                print item2.contents[1].text
                                print item2.contents[2].text
                                print item2.contents[3].text
                                print item2.contents[4].text
                                print item2.contents[5].text
                                print item2.contents[6].text
                                print item2.contents[7].text
                                print item2.contents[8].text

                    browser.back()
                    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".add-listing")))
################### END ---- This is where the code is not executing END ---#######################
                    ############ END SCRAPE INFO ####################
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    browser.back()
                    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pagenav")))

        else:
            browser.back()
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pagenav")))
            print "Number of listings: 0"

        browser.back()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pagenav")))
```

By the way this is some of the result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Getting listings for 'Plumbers'
Number of listings:  5
Cleaned string:  ['Hydroflame Plumbing & Gas Ltd']
Cleaned string:  ['Osborne Plumbing Ltd']
Cleaned string:  ['Plumbers Auckland Central']
Cleaned string:  ['Griffiths Plumbing']
Cleaned string:  ['Plumber Auckland']
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Getting listings for 'Professional Services'
Number of listings:  2
Cleaned string:  ['North Shore Chiropractor']
Cleaned string:  ['Psychotherapy Werks - Rob Hunter']
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Getting listings for 'Property Maintenance'
Number of listings:  7
Cleaned string:  ['Auckland Tree Services']
Cleaned string:  ['Bob the Tree Man']
Cleaned string:  ['Flawless House Washing & Drain Unblocking']
Cleaned string:  ['Yardiez']
Cleaned string:  ['Build Corp Apartments Albany']
Cleaned string:  ['Auckland Trellis']
Cleaned string:  ['Landscape Design']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found a solution after thinking @jeffC's suggestion:

- extract the href values and append it to the base url which is *http://aucklandtradesmen.co.nz*, so for example the if the extracted href is */home-mainmenu-1/alarms-a-security/armed-alarms-ltd-.html*,and tell browser to navigate to that URL..and then I can do whatever I want in the current page..

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is change the logic some. Here's the logic flow I would suggest you use. This will eliminate the writing off of the links and speed up the script.

```
1. Navigate to http://aucklandtradesmen.co.nz/
2. Grab all elements using CSS selector "#index a" and store the attribute "href" of each
   in an array of string (links to each category page)
3. Loop through the href array
   3.1. Navigate to href
        3.1.1. Grab all elements using CSS selector "div.listing-summary a" and store the
               .text of each (company names)
        3.1.2. If an element .by_link_text("Next") exists, click it and return to 3.1.1.
```

If you want business contact info off of the company pages, you would want to store the href in 3.1.1. and then loop through that list and grab what you want off the page.

---

Sorry about the weirdness of the formatting of the list. It won't let me indent more than one level.

Comment: thanks, this is ideal for some intermediate learners..right now sticking to my code and pinpoint its errors are helpful..

Comment: Well I would argue that starting with good logical flow is more important many times than the code you write. You can write the best code ever but if your logic is off, you script will still be slow, etc. I think being a better programmer is about learning both.. learning good logical flow along with good coding.